# Skyscreamer validate just few paths

Tags: java

I have huge jsons and want to validate just some paths. I don't want to stay and compute each path for ignoring that field like:

```
new Customization(".id", (o, t1) -> true)
```

I **cannot create my own class Customization** because it is **not implementing any interface** and also i **cannot override** the `matches` method because the **class if final**.

Can i solve this with `Skyscreamer` or i need another library?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like that?

```java
public class IgnoreValueMatcher implements ValueMatcher {
    @Override
    public boolean equal(Object o, Object t1) {
        return true;
    }
}

//...

JSONAssert.assertEquals(expectedJsonString, actualJsonString,
        new CustomComparator(JSONCompareMode.LENIENT,
                new Customization("id", new IgnoreValueMatcher()),
        )
);
```

Comment: This is the way to do it but i don't want this because i want to validate just some paths from inner json. So its possible to need to write 50 ignores for just 3 validations.

Comment: They have [open issue](https://github.com/skyscreamer/JSONassert/issues/15) about it and it seems they aren't t going to close it. You would contribute their project :) Else, you must be pass a multiple instances of `Customization` in your `CustomComparator`